# Returning empty array from the recursive function expressjs?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, async-await

I am trying to get all child element from MongoDB,
I have written a recursive function to get all child elements.
It loops through all value, I can able to console log all values
inside the loop when I push values to an array and return the value I am getting an empty array.
I am writing this code in expressjs 
code is below

```js
static async getAllChildCat(categoryId){

    var allCat = [];

    let test = async (categoryId) => {
        let category = await NewCategory.find({ 'parent': categoryId });
        if (category.length > 0) {
            await category.forEach(async elem => {
                let newVal = await test(elem._id);
                console.log(elem);
                allCat.push(elem);
            });
        }
    }

    var val = await test(categoryId);

    return allCat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`test` is an async function and therefore you will return an empty `allCat` array. You need to call it with `await test(categoryId)` so the return statement waits for `test` to resolve.

Comment: if you add await also it gives empty array. that I have tried please check above code, i have updated